# Laravel - Customize error message that using Rule class

Tags: laravel, validation, rules

Based on the Laravel's documentation, the way to edit error message is like this:

```
$messages = [
    'email.required' => 'We need to know your e-mail address!',
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

But what if the rule is using `Rule` class?

For example:

```
$rules = [
    'img_type'      => ['required', Rule::in(['png', 'jpeg', 'gif'])],
];

$messages = [
    'img_type.{what-to-type-here-for-Rule::in}' => 'Invalid image type',
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

As the example above, `img_type.{what-to-type-here-for-Rule::in}`, I don't know how to specify the custom error message for `Rule::in`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule is just called [`in`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-in). So this is what you have to use.

```
$messages = [
    'img_type.in' => 'Invalid image type',
];
```

Exactly as it is defined in the [default translations](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/lang/en/validation.php#L60).